# Formatting an external HDD with Bash script

Tags: shell-script, command-line, filesystems

At my workplace we have an external HDD connected to a NAS device (Synology).

There is a backup tasks which runs weekly and fills the external HDD after a while. Unfortunately the Linux-based OS of the Synology Rack Station does not provide an automated task scheduling for formatting which can be done is a user friendly way. But, there is an options which allows running user defined *.sh scripts on the NAS in a certain time & date.

The problem here is that I am not really familiar with bash code, to be able to write a script which will format the external HDD in ext4 filesystem.

Could anyone please provide such a code here, or maybe pointers to any sites that contain the required information?

Comment: I don't understand why you want the disks to be formatted. Can you elaborate? This is not normally necessary for backups.

Comment: @FaheemMitha the external HDDs are used to keep only the most recent (last 3 days) backups. We have only 2 external HDDS in hand, which suffice to keep the whole weeks backup. For our scenario that has worked fine so far

Comment: Ok, but why not just delete the files?

Answer (score 2):

```
while read -r line; do
mkfs.ext4 "$line"
done < <(df -k | grep 'media' | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

The `df` command with the `grep` and `cut` pipes would give us the list of external hard drive mounts.

For instance, the external hard disk will always get mounted automatically to `/media` in most of the systems. So, I am using `df` command to check the mounts of the external HDD partitions. The reason is I do not want to mount the existing file system in the machine.

After finding it, I use it in a `while` loop to create a `ext4` file system on the partitions.

Comment: it should be saved as a `*.sh` file, right?

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne, yes. It should be saved as .sh and appropriate permissions need to be set for the script. I would suggest you to test it once before putting it as a `cron` job.